# ubuntu touch on non-brand name tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet

I have just gotten a non-name brand android table running 4.0.4 and the model number is A13-MID.  Curious as to if this non-brand tablet would be able to have the new ubuntu touch os that just came out?  and if so then would I just follow the basic instructions that has been up on the ubuntu website? I'm afraid since it's not a Nexus phone or tablet then I won't be able to do it.